# datastructure/abtract data type with C which acts like vectors in C++

Tags: c++, c

Hi I am using a C compiler(GCC) where I cannot use a vector like in C++. So how can I create similar kind of data structure/dynamic array with c which will work like a vector? It might be very easy but I don't have any idea how can I do it.

thanks

Comment: The search term you want is "dynamic array". It's a pretty common method. You'll get a lot of use out of `realloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a struct holding a pointer to the correct type the currently used size, and the current allocation size. Allocate space with malloc. If you run out of space, use realloc to increase it.

Comment: thanks for your reply can you please give me some documents link explaining the same.